# Ejecutar una función al finalizar una compra en woocommer

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

Buen día a todos.
Quisiera que al terminar el checkout en Woocommerce, se active una función que tengo hecha en php. Podría migrarla de lenguaje, pero quisiera saber cómo hacer para insertar un hook que llame y ejecute a esa función al finalizar una compra.
En qué lenguaje debe estar escrita la función?.
Un saludo y gracias.